# C# How to replace an accent insensitive string with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to perform an accent-insensitive replace in a string. I want 'client' to match 'cliënt' and vice versa.

My code looks like this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("client");
string result = reg.Replace("here goes the content with client and cliënt", "replacementWith");
```

So, how do I make sure that 'client' matches 'client' and 'cliënt' and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

You can include it in the Regex

```
Regex reg = new Regex("cli[eë]nt"); // will match both 'client' and 'cliënt'
```

or you can remove all the accents in the string and then apply the regular expression.

```
string test = "here góes the cóntent with client and cliënt";

char[] replacement = { 'a','a','a','a','a','a','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','n','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','y' };
char[] accents = { 'à','á','â','ã','ä','å','ç','é','è','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ñ','ò','ó','ô','ö','õ','ù','ú','û','ü','ý','ÿ' };


for (int i = 0; i < accents.Length; i++)
{
    test = test.Replace(accents[i], replacement[i]);
}
```

This is not very efficient but will do the job for small amounts of text.

Comment: Be sure to run your string through a [Unicode normalization process](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) before stripping accent marks, however.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough. Client was just an example. I want a general manner of replacing accent insensitive strings.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have to deal with documents. So a document can be small, but it can also be very large. I will consider using this approach.

Comment: Definitely don't use this method on large amounts of text as it copies the string 27 times. The best way I guess is to go through the string character by character and replace if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0sbec17.aspx)

Bear in mind that you need to work in a specific culture though - there's no arbitrary accent-replacement culture, since in one culture e and ë might be considered equivalent, in another they might be different.

Comment: I've modified my regex with `Regex reg = new Regex("client", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);` but I have not specified my culture. Is this necessarily? Or do I look for a culture where `e` and `ë` mean the same..:p

Comment: Sorry, on more reading, it doesn't look like CultureInvariant is enough. I can tell you how to do proper accent-insensitive comparisons using the `CompareInfo` class and `IgnoreNonSpace` options, but not using Regexs :(

Comment: Doesn't matter, Thnx for the effort though :)